# Pandas - aggregating values for a defined period of time before and after a date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of names and tokens where each name is associated with a unique token and there are two aggregate costs linked to each token. The dates of when the tokens were used is given.

```
    Token   Name  AggCost1  AggCost2        Date
0  token1  nameX        26        70  2019-01-01
1  token2  nameY       100       120  2018-11-11
```

From the date in the first table I want to aggregate Cost1 and Cost2 in the second table below for each name that appears in the first table within a time interval of 3 months before a particular token is used (date denoted -3mo) and 3 months after it is used (date denoted +3mo). In this table, the relationship between name and token is one-to-many.

```
    Name        Date   Token  Cost1  Cost2
0  nameX  2018-10-03  tokenA      0     30
1  nameX  2018-12-12  tokenB     40     20
2  nameX  2019-01-01  token1     26     70
3  nameY  2018-09-01  tokenC    150    200
4  nameY  2018-07-04  tokenD     10     20
5  nameY  2019-01-01     NaN     50     50
6  nameY  2018-11-11  token2     50     20
7  nameY  2018-11-11  token2     50    100
```

The following is what I would like to output:

```
    Token   Name  AggCost1  AggCost2        Date        -3mo  -3moCost1  -3moCost2        +3mo  +3moCost1  +3moCost2
0  token1  nameX        26        70  2019-01-01  2018-10-01         40         50  2019-04-01          0          0
1  token2  nameY       100       120  2018-11-11  2018-08-11        150        200  2019-02-11         50         50
```

What I'm having trouble generating is this intermediary table. I'm not sure how to gather the rows for each name into buckets of -/+3 months based on `Date` in the first table.

```
    Name        Date        -3mo  -3moCost1  -3moCost2        +3mo  +3moCost1  +3moCost2
0  nameX  2019-01-01  2018-10-01         40         50  2019-03-31          0          0
1  nameY  2018-11-11  2018-08-11        150        200  2019-02-11         50         50
```

Comment: please can you share samples of your dataframes not images so that you're problem is easier to reproduce

Comment: More generically, could [window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) functions help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to cobble something together. I've broken down the steps I took below.

My starting dataframes:

`df1`

```
    Token   Name  AggCost1  AggCost2      Date1
0  token1  nameX        26        70 2019-01-01
1  token2  nameY       100       120 2018-11-11
```

`df2`

```
    Name      Date2   Token  Cost1  Cost2
0  nameX 2018-10-03  tokenA      0     30
1  nameX 2018-12-12  tokenB     40     20
2  nameX 2019-01-01  token1     26     70
3  nameY 2018-09-01  tokenC    150    200
4  nameY 2018-07-04  tokenD     10     20
5  nameY 2019-01-01     NaN     50     50
6  nameY 2018-11-11  token2     50     20
7  nameY 2018-11-11  token2     50    100
```

Get the dates for three months before and after Date1 using `DateOffset`

```
df1['-3mo'] = df1['Date1'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3)
df1['+3mo'] = df1['Date1'] + pd.DateOffset(months=3)
```

Merge `df1` and `df2`

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='Name')
```

```
  Token_x   Name  AggCost1  AggCost2      Date1       -3mo       +3mo      Date2 Token_y  Cost1  Cost2
0  token1  nameX        26        70 2019-01-01 2018-10-01 2019-04-01 2018-10-03  tokenA      0     30
1  token1  nameX        26        70 2019-01-01 2018-10-01 2019-04-01 2018-12-12  tokenB     40     20
2  token1  nameX        26        70 2019-01-01 2018-10-01 2019-04-01 2019-01-01  token1     26     70
3  token2  nameY       100       120 2018-11-11 2018-08-11 2019-02-11 2018-09-01  tokenC    150    200
4  token2  nameY       100       120 2018-11-11 2018-08-11 2019-02-11 2018-07-04  tokenD     10     20
5  token2  nameY       100       120 2018-11-11 2018-08-11 2019-02-11 2019-01-01     NaN     50     50
6  token2  nameY       100       120 2018-11-11 2018-08-11 2019-02-11 2018-11-11  token2     50     20
7  token2  nameY       100       120 2018-11-11 2018-08-11 2019-02-11 2018-11-11  token2     50    100
```

Keep rows where Date2 falls within the time duration of either 3 months before or 3 months after Date1

```
df = df.loc[(df['Date2'] >= df['-3mo']) & (df['Date2'] < df['Date1']) 
       | (df['Date2'] > df['Date1']) & (df['Date2'] <= df['+3mo'])]
```

Create a column that segments the rows into either the -3mo or +3mo bucket

```
df['3mo'] = np.where(df['Date2'] > df['Date1'], '+3', '-3')
```

Use the new column to get the aggregates for Cost1 and Cost2

```
df['3mo_Cost1'] = df.groupby(['3mo', 'Name'])['Cost1'].transform('sum')
df['3mo_Cost2'] = df.groupby(['3mo', 'Name'])['Cost2'].transform('sum')
```

Separate out 3mo_Cost1 and 3mo_Cost2 into two columns

```
df['-3moCost1'] = np.where(df['3mo'] == '-3', df['3mo_Cost1'], 0)
df['+3moCost1'] = np.where(df['3mo'] == '+3', df['3mo_Cost1'], 0)
df['-3moCost2'] = np.where(df['3mo'] == '-3', df['3mo_Cost2'], 0)
df['+3moCost2'] = np.where(df['3mo'] == '+3', df['3mo_Cost2'], 0)
```

After some cleaning, this is the final output:

```
  Token_x   Name  AggCost1  AggCost2      Date1       -3mo  -3moCost1  -3moCost2       +3mo  +3moCost1  +3moCost2
0  token1  nameX        26        70 2019-01-01 2018-10-01         40         50 2019-04-01          0          0
3  token2  nameY       100       120 2018-11-11 2018-08-11        150        200 2019-02-11          0          0
5  token2  nameY       100       120 2018-11-11 2018-08-11          0          0 2019-02-11         50         50
```